# upload files using sftp with proxy(http) using python-paramiko

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko, http-proxy

I am new to python paramiko. I am trying to upload files in my client server with sftp using python-paramiko. I have code without proxy setup. Please find that below.

```
host = "abc.mno.com"
port = 22
proxy_uri = "http://username:password@proxyIP:port"
url = urlparse(proxy_uri)
http_con = http.client.HTTPConnection(url.hostname, url.port)
print(url.hostname)
http_con.trust_env=False
headers = {}
if url.username and url.password:
    auth = '%s:%s' % (url.username, url.password)
    headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = 'Basic '+auth
    print(headers)
    http_con.set_tunnel(host, port, headers)
    http_con.connect()
    sock = http_con.sock    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.connect(
        hostname=host,
        port=port,
        username='username',
        key_filename="E:\\keyfile.pem",
        sock=sock,
        )
    print('connected')
```

I am trying this in windows server. When I execute the program, I am getting error stating "OSError: Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required". How can I authenticate the proxy.
Could anyone please help me to connect to sftp with proxy(http) setup.

Comment: *"I just want to use proxy in the python script alone"* – That's what the answer by @tintin to the duplicate question does, isn't it?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, I cannot install tinyproxy in windows(@tintin mentioned this as step 1). Also, proxy which I am using has username and password. I am totally new to this paramiko and proxy.

Comment: The tinyproxy is mentioned there as a **test proxy** against which the code was tested. It's not part of the solution. – *"all you need is any proxy that allows you to CONNECT to your ssh port".*

Comment: got it. Thanks. I tried the below code for proxy setup. I am getting error stating "OSError: Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required". How can I provide proxy authentication.

Comment: Check the new link I've added to the list of duplicates.

Comment: I have used Proxy-Authorization and encoded it as mentioned in that link. Still I am  getting same error(OSError: Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required).

Comment: I do not see any base64 encoding in your code.

Comment: Also, when I print headers, I am getting "{'Proxy-Authorization':b'Abcederfghijklmnopqrsty='}". Is this the correct format?

Comment: for encoding, I have changed the below line.
headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = base64.b64encode(('Basic '+ auth).encode())

Comment: No it's not. As my answer says, you encode only the credentials, not the `Basic` prefix.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222645/discussion-between-karthi-kyan-and-martin-prikryl).